# How to control whether the tab key should insert tabs or spaces in sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext

I have some code,  I want to format it and add spaces instead of tabs when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>

```
 $this->data['clients']     = $this->Clients_model->selectAll();
 $this->data['closed']      = $this->Activity_model->getclosed(); 
 $this->data['closedNum']   = $this->Activity_model->closedRows();
```

How to change configuration of sublime to do that? 
I tried  [Indentation Settings](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/indentation.html) in sublime documentation but my files not the same name as given in the site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to View -> Indentation -> Indent Using Spaces